How to compare Notes Item on Type using OpenNTF Domino API?
I am applying the OpenNTF Domino API to an existing application.
In my code I get a lot of warnings that the method getType is depricated. I have no idea how to rewrite the code.
The code is as follwed:
if (doc.hasItem("fieldA")) {                
    Item rtiComment = doc.getFirstItem("fieldA");               
    if (null != rtiComment) {                    
        if (rtiComment.getType() == Item.MIME_PART) {   //here I get a warning           
            //more code
        } else if (rtiComment.getType() == Item.RICHTEXT) { //here I get a warning      
            //more code
        }   
    }               
}

I read in the documentation that there is another method getTypeEx() for an Item, but this returns a Type. I Have no idea how to get the type of the Item.MIME_PART because according to the documentation that returns an integer.
What am I misunderstanding and what should I adapt to my code to be able to compare the Item and get rid off all the warnins that I get?
Thanks+Much appreciated!

You can continue to use getType as it's just marked as deprecated but your code will work.
The suggest getTypeEx method returns an enum so your code example would look like this:
if (doc.hasItem("fieldA")) {                
    Item rtiComment = doc.getFirstItem("fieldA");               
    if (null != rtiComment) {                    
        if (rtiComment.getTypeEx() == Type.MIME_PART) {           
            //more code
        } else if (rtiComment.getTypeEx() == Type.RICHTEXT) {      
            //more code
        }   
    }               
}

Type is org.openntf.domino.Item.Type.
